# How to prevent a field from wrapping in Views?

Tags: views, theming

I have a price field that gets squished and displays on multilines instead of a single line. The only way to solve this is to apply some css wrap magic?

Answer (score 0):

With css you could set a specific width or use white-space:nowrap. I don't know how to do it other than with css or javascript